# Python Requests Returns 400

Tags: python, python-requests, slack

i have this command

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#test\", \"username\": \"kuhkuh\", \"text\": \"This is posted to #test\", \"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/123/123/123
```

im trying to create it using python so i can use it on my project

```
import requests
import json

class SlackWrapper:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def post_message_to_slack(self, err):

        url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/123/123/123'

        payload = {
            'channel' :  '#test',
            'username' :  'kuhkuh',
            'message' : err,
            'icon_emoji' : ':ghosts:'
        }
        
        try:
            alert = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            print(alert.status_code, ' - ', alert.text, ' - ', json.dumps(payload))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

SlackWrapper.post_message_to_slack("testing error message requests")
```

the problem is, i keep geting this error

```
<Response [400]>
```

where did i went wrong?

Comment: Try `print(alert.status, ' - ', print(alert.text))`

Comment: it gives this

invalid_payload
400  -  None

Comment: `print(alert.status, ' - , alert.text)` - fixed line;

Comment: see text error from slack API, most likely your payload is not in the correct format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to send the data to the server as a dictionary.

Instead try sending it as a json data using requests POST [json attribute](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=json#requests.post)

```py
payload = {
    "channel" =  '#test',
    "username" =  'kuhkuh',
    "message" = err,
    "icon_emoji" = ':ghosts:'
}

alert = requests.post(url, json = payload)
```

Comment: i did, i gives invalid payload.

Comment: print(alert.status_code, ' - ', alert.text, ' - ', json.dumps(payload))

400  -  invalid_payload  -  {"channel": "#test", "username": "kuhkuh", "message": "testing error message requests", "icon_emoji": ":ghosts:"}

Comment: If you were using `data` and json.dumps, try using `headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` as a function argument. If you were using `json`, requests should have automatically sent a json header. (Remember to not use json.dumps on the payload if you use the `json` arg...

Comment: @Boidushya That was also the mistake in my answer, using `json.dumps`

Comment: Also make sure the payload you sent was in the correct format.

Comment: the dict `payload` is not valid syntax

Comment: assuming that the cURL request worked, you might wanna try this one  :) `response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})` (the payload being the payload in my original answer)

Comment: yeah the cURL request worked, i edited the code according to suggestion, still error 400 :v

Comment: That's strange, if it worked then the above answer should've worked too ... Might wanna check [this](https://gist.github.com/devStepsize/b1b795309a217d24566dcc0ad136f784) out!

Comment: Great to know it worked! Might wanna accept the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 means "Bad Request", so your payload is wrong.

If your `payload` is already a `dict` there is no need to `json.dumps` it in the `json` parameter of the `post request`. Also `requests` is smart enough to infer the `Content-Type`, so no need to explicitly set this Header.

```
@classmethod
    def post_message_to_slack(self, err):

        url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/123/123/123'
        
        # changed the payload
        payload = {
            "channel": "#test", 
            "username": "kuhkuh", 
            "text": "This is posted to #test",
            "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"
        }
        
        try:
            # changed the parameters for posting
            alert = requests.post(url, json=payload) 
            print(alert.status_code, ' - ', alert.text, ' - ', json.dumps(payload))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the curl code to postman then get the python code and use that.
For your code the equivalent python code :

```
import requests

url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/123/123/123"

payload = 'payload=%7B%22channel%22%3A%20%22%23test%22%2C%20%22username%22%3A%20%22kuhkuh%22%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22This%20is%20posted%20to%20%23test%22%2C%20%22icon_emoji%22%3A%20%22%3Aghost%3A%22%7D'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```